# Inserting copied cells then referencing back to original cells using replace function

Tags: string, replace, insert, offset

I am currently trying to write a macro that essentially takes a column,duplicates it to the right, then changes certain references to refer back to the previous column.

I am using the replace method, but because i am looking for a specific string based on the column letter and "2" I used an object to bring together the column letter and the "2".A better way to explain is say I copied column B and inserted it and made a duplicate in column C.

I now want to find "C2 and "C3" in my formulas and change them to "B2" and "B3".

I figured this would be done by finding the aforementioned strings by using the replace method and offsetting them by -1. This has proved rather difficult. Any ideas?

```
'duplicates column over 1'

ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Select
Selection.Copy
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone
Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Declarations and Instantiations'
Dim rngo As Range, cell As Range, ranger As Range
Dim lookfor As String
Dim UsedRng As Range, LastRow As Long
Set rngo = Selection.EntireColumn
Set UsedRng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
LastRow = UsedRng(UsedRng.Cells.Count).Row

rngo.Select

Do Until ActiveCell.Row = LastRow + 1

For Each cell In rngo

Col = SPLIT(ActiveCell(1).Address(1, 0), "$")(0) 'returns just the cell letter'

lookfor = (Col & "2") 'combines the column letter with the number(I BELIEVE THIS IS THE SOURCE OF THE ISSUE BUT IM NOT SURE IN WHAT WAY'

'starts to search the new column for "lookfor" which is just the designated string'
rngo.Replace _What:=lookfor, Replacement:="'offset lookfor by 1 column'",_SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True

Next cell
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop

MsgBox ColumnName(Selection)
MsgBox lookfor

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved: change " rngo.Replace" to "ActiveCell.Replace"